# jquery append(str); not taking string value

Tags: jquery

I needed to append a new textfield when user clicks `button(#add)`.But `append(str);` is not taking value of str.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
   $('#add').click(function()
   {
      var str = '<li>';
      str+= '<label>Name</label><input type="text" value=""/> ';
      str+= '<input type="button" value="remove"
      class="remove"/>';
      str+= '</li>';

      $('#sites').append(str);
   });

   $('.remove').live('click', function()
   {
      $(this).parent('li').remove();
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in one line:

```
str+= '<input type="button" value="remove" class="remove"/>';
```

---

Here must be a syntax error because of new line character.

```
str+= '<input type="button" value="remove"
  class="remove"/>';
```

[Demo with fix in place](http://jsbin.com/qabeteyi/1/)

Comment: Not mine, I think you've hit the nail on the head :)

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax error while concatenating the string, so try to write your code in a cleaner way like this to get rid of those kind of errors.

Try,

```
$('#sites').append($('<li>').append(
                   $('<label>',{ text:"Name" }),
                   $('<input>',{ type:"text",value:"" }),
                   $('<input>',{ type:"button",class:"remove",value:"remove" })));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qabeteyi/2/edit)

Demo derived from JAI's answer